# Going through a list and checking in Python

Tags: python, list, conditional-statements

I'm currently looking for an algorithm to be able to go through a list such as the following one: `[1,1,1,1,2,3,4,5,5,5,3,2]`
I want, in this example, to be able to select the first "1" as there's a duplicate next to it, and keep going through the list until finding the next number having a duplicate next to it, and then select the last number of this one (ie. "5" in this example).
Eventually, make the difference between these 2 numbers (ie. 5-1)

I have this code at the moment:

```
i=0    

for i in range(len(X)):

    if (X[i] == X[i+1]):
        first_number = X[i]

    elif (X[i] != X[i+1]):
        i+=1
```

I'd like to add a further condition to my question. Suppose you have the following list: lst=[1,1,1,1,2,3,4,5,5,5,3,3,3,3,2,2,2,4,3] In this case, I'll get the following differences according to your code = lst = [4,-2,-1] and then stops. However, I'd like "4-2" to be added to the list afterwards because "4" is followed by a number less than "4" (thus, going to the opposite direction - up - of what "2" followed "4" were following). I hope this is clear enough. Many thanks

Comment: Could you provide example input and output of what this algorithm should do? Where does the difference (ie 5-1) get added?

Comment: So, are you looking for the difference between the first duplicate and the second duplicate?

Comment: Once you have the first number, `break`. Then do a similar look over `range(len(X) - 1, -1, -1)` going backwards to find the last one.

Comment: Also, get rid of the `for` loop or `i=0`. Also, if you do do a for loop, do it over `range(len(X) - 1)`.

Comment: Please clarify: Do you want the difference between the first and the _second_, or the first and the _last_ repeated number?

Comment: @tobias_k I want the difference between the last second repeated number and the first first repeated number (ie. 5 - 1).
Moreover, in the following list, for ex, lst = [1,1,1,1,2,3,4,5,5,5,3,3,3,3,2,2,2], I want that, once "5-1" has been done, we carry on going through the list, such as doing the next difference which is "3-5" before doing the next one which is "3-2".

I hope this is clear enough. 
Many thanks for your answers all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to find groups of repeating numbers, then find the difference between the first two of those:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> lst = [1,1,1,1,2,3,4,5,5,5,3,2]
>>> duplicates = [k for k, g in itertools.groupby(lst) if len(list(g)) > 1] 
>>> duplicates[1] - duplicates[0]
4
```

Or use `duplicates[-1] - duplicates[0]` if you want the difference between the first and the *last* repeated number.

In the more general case, if you want the difference between all pairs of consecutive repeated numbers, you could combine that with `zip`:

```
>>> lst = [1,1,1,1,2,3,4,5,5,5,3,3,3,3,2,2,2]
>>> duplicates = [k for k, g in itertools.groupby(lst) if len(list(g)) > 1] 
>>> duplicates
[1, 5, 3, 2]
>>> [x - y for x,y in zip(duplicates, duplicates[1:])]
[-4, 2, 1]
```

---

I think now I got what you want: You want the difference between any consecutive "plateaus" in the list, where a plateau is either a repeated value, or a local minimum or maximum. This is a bit more complicated and will take several steps:

```
>>> lst=[1,1,1,1,2,3,4,5,5,5,3,3,3,3,2,2,2,4,3]
>>> plateaus = [lst[i] for i in range(1, len(lst)-1) if lst[i] == lst[i-1] 
...                                                  or lst[i-1] <= lst[i] >= lst[i+1] 
...                                                  or lst[i-1] >= lst[i] <= lst[i+1]]
>>> condensed = [k for k, g in itertools.groupby(plateaus)]
>>> [y-x for x, y in zip(condensed, condensed[1:])]
[4, -2, -1, 2]
```

Comment: Dear downvoter, care to explain why the downvote? Do you think I misunderstood the question? In this case, please enlighten me.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Still have some problems. My code is:

from itertools import groupby as itertools

def check_f1(X):
    
    duplicates = [k for k, g in itertools.groupby(X) if len(list(g)) > 1]
    duplicates[1] - duplicates[0]

Comment: @sammtt Your import is wrong: Instead of `from itertools import groupby as itertools` just do `import itertools`

Comment: Thanks very much. However, I don't understand why the first element is "-4" ??

Comment: @sammtt It is `-4` because I did `x - y` in the list comprehension, but of course you can as well do `y - x`, or `abs(x - y)`.

Comment: Thank you. Actually I'd like to add a further condition to my question. Suppose you have the following list: lst=[1,1,1,1,2,3,4,5,5,5,3,3,3,3,2,2,2,4,3]
In this case, I'll get the following differences according to your code = lst = [4,-2,-1] and then stops. However, I'd like "4-2" to be added to the list afterwards because "4" is followed by a number less than "4" (thus, going to the opposite direction - up - of what "2" followed "4" were following). I hope this is clear enough. Many thanks @tobias_k

Comment: @sammtt No, not really clear. Why do you want to have `4` at all? The `4` is not repeated in your example. If you want the result of the difference to be positive, just use `abs(x-y)`.

Comment: actually I have two cases in which subtraction would occur:
1) the one previously elaborated
2) my new case: consider the list [2,2,2,3,4,3]. I'd like to make "4-2" as "4" is here a local maximum. Another example, consider the list, [6,6,6,2,2,2,3,4,3]. In this case, two subtractions will be carried out: "2-6" and "4-2".
Another example, consider the list [6,6,6,2,2,2,3,4,3,7]. Here, 3 subtractions will be carried out: "2-6", "4-2", and "3-4"
Hope it's clear now

Comment: I think I understand now what you want: You want to get sort of the "minima" and "maxima" as well as the "plateaus". What about `[1,3,3,2]`? Here, `3` is both a maximum and a plateau. Do you want `3-1` and `2-3)`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `enumerate` with a starting index of `1`. Duplicates are detected if the current value is equal to the value at the previous index:

```
l = [1,1,1,1,2,3,4,5,5,5,3,2]
r = [v for i, v in enumerate(l, 1) if i < len(l) and v == l[i]]

result = r[-1] - r[0]
# 4
```

The list `r` is a list of all duplicates. `r[-1]` is the last item and `r[0]` is the first.

More trials:

```
>>> l= [1,1,5,5,5,2,2]
>>> r = [v for i, v in enumerate(l, 1) if i < len(l) and v == l[i]]
>>> r[-1] - r[0]
1
```

Comment: Hm, I guess OP's question is a bit ambiguous: In one sentence, he's looking for the "next" duplicate number, and then he takes the difference between the "last" and the first...

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

```
def subDupeLimits( aList ):
    dupList = []
    prevX = None
    for x in aList:
        if x == prevX:
            dupList.append(x) # track duplicates
        prevX = x # update previous x

    # return last duplicate minus first
    return dupList[-1] - dupList[0]

# call it
y = subDupeLimits( [1,1,1,1,2,3,4,5,5,5,3,2] )
# y =  4
```